# run query on mongo console return specific array object but trying to get console result for the same query in MeteorJS it return document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

db.companySettings.find({'-id':"9uvjCujcjSbbLYi86"},{'companyEmployeeCategory':1})

When above query run on mongo command prompt it return answer as follows

```
{
   "_id":"9uvjCujcjSbbLYi86",
    "companyEmployeeCategory":[
       "ES",
       "OS",
       "OS",
       "ED"
    ]
}
```

when,I write same query in METEORJS ,I am getting following answer

```
Object
_id
:
"9uvjCujcjSbbLYi86"
companyContactNumber1
:
"9623445566"
companyContactNumber2
:
"9604563322"
companyDepartment
:
Array[2]
companyDesignation
:
Array[2]
companyEmail1
:
"iassureit@gmail.com"
companyEmail2
:
"iassureit123@gmail.com"
companyEmployeeCategory
:
Array[7]
companyLocationsInfo
:
Array[2]
companyName
:
"iAssureIT"
companyWebsite
:
"www.iassureit.com"
facebook
:
"iassureit@facebook.com"
generalSettings
:
Array[1]
industryDomain
:
"IT"
leavePolicy
:
Array[4]
linkedInkey
:
"iassureit@linkedin.com"
publicHolidays
:
Array[2]
twitter
:
"iassureit@twitter.com"
youtube
:
"iassureit@youtube.com"
__proto__
:
Object
```

Comment: can you please be more elaborative? Since it's not clear what is your query when in MeteorJS

Comment: CompanySettings.find({'-id':"9uvjCujcjSbbLYi86"},{'companyEmployeeCategory':1}); This is my query in MeteorJs and CompanySettings is an object of my collection companySettings

Comment: You are using find method of mongoDb which returns a cursor , if you just want to get a single document then use 'findOne' method  and for getting multiple documents use 'find({<your conditions>}).fetch()' method